# How can I put my @keyframes declaration inline in my HTML/SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

Ok, so I have this HTML code for an **I Love You** animation. And I'm having some difficult time to adjust it as an inline code.

Is this possible in any way?

```css
.heart {
  fill: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  animation: pulse 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
I 

<svg class="heart" viewBox="0 0 32 29.6">
  <path d="M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2
    c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z"/>
</svg> 

You
```

Comment: You can't put an animation as an inline style.

Comment: @Paulie_D Didn't know that. That's why I've been punching my head against the wall for several minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @weegee semicolons aren't required for the last property-value pair in a CSS selector declaration, so one not being there is not an error.

Comment: @TylerH No, a semi-colon is not required on the last property. but a comma will cause the line to *not be recognised by the browser* and so will fail. Hence this IS a typo issue - over and above the "inline" issue,

Comment: @Paulie_D First, the comma was a typo in transcription over to Stack Overflow which OP corrected nearly 30 minutes ago, so, no, this is still not a typo issue. Second, I was addressing weegee's (now deleted) comment which said it wasn't working *because it was missing a semicolon on the last line*, which was an incorrect claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like below with pure SVG and no external CSS (only inline)

```html
I 

<svg class="heart" viewBox="0 0 32 29.6" width="50" style="overflow:visible;position: relative;top: 5px;">
<g transform-origin="center">
 <path d="M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2
    c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z" fill="red"/>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                type="scale"
                keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="1;1.3;1"
                dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                
    </g>
</svg> 

You
```

Answer (score 3):

You might include the style into `svg` element itself:

```html
I

<svg class="heart" viewBox="0 0 32 29.6">
  <style>
    .heart {
      fill: red;
      position: relative;
      top: 5px;
      width: 50px;
      animation: pulse 1s ease infinite
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
      0% { transform: scale(1); }
      50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
      100% { transform: scale(1); }
    }
  </style>
  <path d="M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2
    c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z"/>
</svg>

You
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place the keyframe and css inside the styles tag inside svg. Like here

```
<svg">
   <style type="text/css">
     .heart {
       fill: red;
       position: relative;
       top: 5px;
       width: 50px;
       animation: pulse 1s ease infinite, 
     }
     @keyframes pulse {
       0% { transform: scale(1); }
       50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
       100% { transform: scale(1); }
     }
  </style>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/WvYJQP.

But the inline can not be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scoped style. It will only affect his direct parent and content.

```html
I 

<svg class="heart" viewBox="0 0 32 29.6">
<style scoped>
.heart {
  fill: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  animation: pulse 1s ease infinite; 
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(1.3); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); }
}
</style>
  <path d="M23.6,0c-3.4,0-6.3,2.7-7.6,5.6C14.7,2.7,11.8,0,8.4,0C3.8,0,0,3.8,0,8.4c0,9.4,9.5,11.9,16,21.2
    c6.1-9.3,16-12.1,16-21.2C32,3.8,28.2,0,23.6,0z"/>
</svg> 

You
```

Comment: did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I use it very often in advertising content.

Comment: this is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/bkv3ufds/ there is no more scoped CSS since a while